# Pivoting and adding new column in SQL Server Management Studio 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I have a database that looks like this:

```
IndexID QuestionID  AnswerGiven
1       3           Phone
1       7           Strongly Agree
2       8           Agree
2       5           Yes
2       3           Chat
3       6           NULL
3       3           Phone
4       3           Web
4       7           Disagree
```

And I want to write a script to essentially pull out Question #3 into its own column called ContactChannel, like this:

```
IndexID QuestionID  ContactChannel  AnswerGiven
1       7           Phone           Strongly Agree
2       8           Chat            Agree
2       5           Chat            Yes
3       6           Phone           Disagree
4       7           Web             Disagree
```

I'm new to SQL, but I suspect this has something to do with pivoting and sub-queries, and I know it can vary by database  Any ideas for SSMS 2016?

Comment: please tag the database you are using.

Comment: How do you determine which answergiven goes with which contract channel?

Comment: @XQbert, by the IndexID.  Each unique IndexID is a response to a survey, and it's repeated here in the answer table 9 times for each of the 9 answers they made.  I just want to pull one of those answers into its own column.

Comment: Ok, but then how do we know if the answergiven is a contactChannel or should go in answergiven.  for example on indexID 1 why is phone in contract and strongly agree in answergiven  and why is chat listed twice for index2  while yes and agree are in answergiven?

Comment: `SSMS 2016` is just a Database management tool. Please name the RDBMS you are actually using. Is it SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server.  Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.IndexID, t1.QuestionID, t2.AnswerGiven AS ContactChannel, t1.AnswerGiven
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.IndexID = t2.IndexID AND t2.QuestionID = 3
WHERE t1.QuestionID <> 3;
```

The query is in ANSI SQL and should work in any RBDMS.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/CIS33202)

Comment: This worked and is a more simple, straightforward answer for a SQL beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` window function to do this, assuming there is one row per questionid=3 per indexid.

```
select * from (
select indexid,questionid,
max(case when questionid=3 then answergiven end) over(partition by indexid) as contactchannel,
answergiven
from tbl
) t
where questionid<>3
```